# parse yaml with only value, NOT key-value pair,

Tags: jackson, yaml

I have an yaml document like below -

```
--- 
Village: 
  Persons: 
    -
      name: Tom
      age: 65
      children: 
        - Bob
        - Marla
    - 
      name: Dick
      age: 58
```

It can be easily parsed. Now for conciseness, I would like to make the same document like this -

```
--- 
Village: 
  Persons: 
    - 
      Tom: 
        age: 65
        children: 
          - Bob
          - Marla
    - 
      Dick: 
        age: 58
```

Please note that, essentially it is the same data. How may parse it into a `Person` object like above document? I am using Java with jackson parser.

Obviously I have *Village* and *Person* classes with all the getters and setters. I thought a Person class with the default constructor with a String argument would do the trick, but it is not.

Comment: your 2nd document try to set Tom object and Dick object in List of person object. that's why its not work.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid parsing it as *Tom* or *Dick* object, rather make it a Person object with the names Tom or Dick. E.g. calling with default constructor `Person(String name)`?

Comment: They better question to ask is whether that is the proper way to get conciseness in YAML. You should be looking at using YAML tags and how to appropriately use them in your document instead of abusing interpretation of keys in your program.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom setter for deserialization of Persons inside your `Village` class. Your `Village` class will then look something like this:

```java
public class Village {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonProperty("Persons")
    public void setPersons(Map<String, Person> personMap){
        for (Map.Entry<String, Person> entry : personMap.entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().setName(entry.getKey());
            persons.add(entry.getValue());
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

}
```

Inside the `setPersons` method the Persons from your yaml are consumed as key-value pairs.
As the key in your yaml is the name of the Person, you just iterate the map and use `setName` to inject the name into each `Person` object.
After that you add the Person to the persons list of your `Village`.